# How to add conditions when calculating using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, series, calculated-columns

[image: Data]
I have a dataframe with two numeric columns. I want to add a third column to calculate the difference. But the condition is if the values in the first column are blank or Nan, the difference should be the value in the second column...

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Any suggestions and clues will be appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a situation with conditions, it is just a math operation.. Suppose you have the df:

consider your df using the .sub() method:

```
df['Diff'] = df['August Sales'].sub(df['July Sales'], fill_value=0)
```

returns output:

```
   July Sales  August Sales   Diff
0       459.0           477   18.0
1       422.0           125 -297.0
2       348.0           483  135.0
3       397.0           271 -126.0
4         NaN           563  563.0
5       191.0           325  134.0
6       435.0           463   28.0
7         NaN           479  479.0
8       475.0           473   -2.0
9       284.0           496  212.0
```

Comment: Thank you again d_kennetz.. What if I want to add one more condition that both July and August are NaN and the difference should be 0. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: If they are both NaN the result will be 0. The bit of code that says fill_value=0 means to treat NaN as 0.

Answer (score 2):

You should use vectorised operations where possible. Here you can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Difference'] = np.where(df['July Sales'].isnull(), df['August Sales'],
                            df['August Sales'] - df['July Sales'])
```

However, consider this is precisely the same as considering `NaN` values in `df['July Sales']` to be equal to zero. So you can use [`pd.Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['Difference'] = df['August Sales'] - df['July Sales'].fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Used a sample dataframe, but it shouldn't be hard to comprehend:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, np.nan, 3], 'B': [10, 20, 30, 40]})

def diff(row):
    return row['B'] if (pd.isnull(row['A'])) else (row['B'] - row['A'])

df['C'] = df.apply(diff, axis=1)
```

ORIGINAL DATAFRAME:

```
    A   B   
0   1.0 10  
1   2.0 20  
2   NaN 30  
3   3.0 40
```

AFTER `apply`:

```
    A   B   C
0   1.0 10  9.0
1   2.0 20  18.0
2   NaN 30  30.0
3   3.0 40  37.0
```

Comment: Your value in column C for 30-NaN is NaN, which is not the answer he wants. I think you are overcomplicating this a bit. It is simple subtraction of column2 - column1.

Comment: `apply` + a custom function is not recommended with Pandas where vectorised operations are available.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def diff(row):
    if not row['col1']:
        return row['col2']
    else:
        return row['col1'] - row['col2']

df['col3']= df.apply(diff, axis=1)
```

Comment: `apply` + a custom function is not recommended with Pandas where vectorised operations are available.